# Google Compute Instance not reachable from Kubernetes pod

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have been trying to reach my Google Compute instance on Compute Engine from a pod in a Kubernetes cluster.

Using `curl http://{INTERNAL_IP}:{PORT}/`

I get: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.0.7 port 8080: Connection timed out`

What are the reasons I could not reach my google compute machine from my Kubernetes pod?

They both share the same region, could it be a permission issue?

Comment: it's complicated  suggest you to ssh to the node and do some testing like "ip addr" and "ip route" and"sudo iptables-save" and try to match the route

Comment: just be sure that your instance has a service exposed on the port 8080 and the firewall rules allow the traffic internally and the instance should be in the same zone of your cluster

Comment: my compute instance can be reachable from a pod in a separate kubernetes cluster, so i do not believe it is an issue with the compute instance, but something about the pod's configurations/permissions.

Comment: you mention sometimes is it intermittent ? The pod will use the service account and scopes to make any request outside the node, if you suspect  permission issue compare both cluster Service account permission

Comment: it is not intermittent; no pods in this cluster can reach any of my Google Compute Engine instances via CURL. However in my other cluster, which is created the same way, pods CAN reach the same Compute Engine instances via curl on the internal IP.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by adding a firewall rule in GCP. What I did was create an Ingress firewall rule for all my compute instance VMs for the kubernetes cluster IP. This option can be found under VPC Networks > Firewall Rules.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that you have not configured IP masquerading. This is a form of NAT where masquerading node/pod IP addresses when sending traffic to destinations outside the cluster node’s IP and the Cluster IP range. For more information look at the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent)

Comment: IP masq mostly only applies when a pod wants to reach the internet, not within a VPC